# Use R to import thousands of single XML into 1 large CSV

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to use R to import thousands of single XML files into one data set where each row is just the text for that xml file.

Currently I am using:

```
    file_list <- list.files()

    for (file in file_list){

      # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
      if (!exists("dataset")){
        dataset <- read.table(file, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
     sep="\t") 
        }  
      # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
     if (exists("dataset")){
        temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=FALSE,   
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep="\t")
dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
rm(temp_dataset)
  }}
```

This seems to work but I know there must be a better way to get XML files into either a single large XML or CSV file. Any pointers to the right direction are sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I did something a few months ago that worked properly:

```
require("data.table")

# files path
setwd("path/to/your_data") 

# list containing your file names
file_list = list.files() 

# read data and save in a list
mydata <- lapply(file_list, read.table, header = FALSE, sep = "\t") 
mydata <- rbindlist(mydata) # merge list to one data frame
```

However if you have performance issues you can even parallelise the process:

```
# reading data in parallel cores

require(parallel)

no_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library("parallel")}) # install dependencies in cores
clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("file_list")) # global variables
mydata <- parLapply(cl, file_list, read.table, header = FALSE, sep = '\t') 
mydata <- rbindlist(mydata) # merge list to one data frame
```

depending on the number of cores your machine have it can be x time faster ;)

Comment: Thanks this works and is cleaner than what I was doing also this PC has six cores so X6 :) thanks!!!